# Simple bcrypt Register User and User Login using PHP - is this approach acceptable?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I am learning PHP and have been looking into a suitable way to safely store password data in MySQL.

Following advice from here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php), is this an acceptable way to deal with passwords?

The code is a very basic example and I haven't included things like error checking / checking if user already exists etc. to keep my example concise.

New Register User:

```
$fld_email =    $_POST['fld_email'];
$fld_name =     $_POST['fld_name'];
$fld_pwd =      $_POST['fld_pwd'];

$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($fld_pwd, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 11));

  $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_a_users (fld_email
                                 , fld_name
                                 , fld_pwd
                                 , fld_date) 
                           VALUES (:fld_email
                                 , :fld_name
                                 , :fld_pwd
                                 , now())";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':fld_email', $fld_email);
$stmt->bindParam(':fld_name', $fld_name);
$stmt->bindParam(':fld_pwd', $hashToStoreInDb);

$stmt->execute();
```

New Process Login:

```
$fld_email    = $_POST['fld_email'];
$fld_pwd_form = $_POST['fld_pwd'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT fld_pwd FROM tbl_a_users WHERE fld_email = :email LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $fld_email);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($fld_pwd_form, $row->fld_pwd);

if ($isPasswordCorrect == true) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

There is no error message here, but I wanted to check with experts about whether this is an acceptable approach before I continue work on this area.

I will also be using HTTPS for the login / register pages.

Comment: [This answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/100897/52915) may be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your approach to hashing and storing passwords is acceptable.

**Misc**

- `== true` is not needed, and should never be used. Either directly write `if (password_verify(...)) {...}`, or use `===` (if you don't trust `==`, which you shouldn't in many situations[*]).
- you should generally try to be consistent with your variable naming schemes. Either use camelCase or snake_case, don't mix them.
- I appreciate that you are mostly consistent with your naming overall, as it really helps readability. `:email` is the exception here, so you should change it.
- `fld_pwd_form` also does not fit your general naming scheme. Either append `_form` to all values that are input, or to none (and think about changing it to `_input`).
- Is there a reason for the `fld_` prefix? It reduces readability, so if you can still change your database names, I would remove it.
- `hash` is enough as a name, you don't need `ToStoreInDb`.

<sub>[*] `==` should be ok for `password_verify`, as it is very unlikely that the function will be changed to return anything else than `true` or `false` in the future. On the other hand, it is PHP, so who knows. And `"1"`, `1`, `-1`, `["error"]`, `"error"` are all `true`.</sub>